# html5 theme for search client

Tags: html, search, client

I am looking for html5 themes for a search engine client. It will be great if infinite srcolling (pagination) and ajax capabilities are already incorporated in the theme and other features that will add value for a search client.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What you have done so far ?

Comment: I have not designed anything so far, just trying to find solution that I can use

Comment: Try to read about [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)